# jquery - Add body class after scroll amount on large screens

Tags: jquery, scroll, resize, window-resize

I've read through a couple different threads and can't quite get this to work. I'm trying to add a class to the body tag after a dynamic scroll amount and only on non-mobile window widths (>= 768)

Here is my current code. Any help is much appreciated!

```js
 var $document = $(document),
     $element = $('body'), //body tag - to have class appended
     $topHeight = $('.slider_image').height() + 75, //height of the slider div (dynamic) + the height of the navbar (75px)
     className = 'sticky-scroll'; //class I want to add to <body>
 $document.scroll(function() { //function to run on pageload
     if ($(window).width() >= 768) && ($document.scrollTop() >= $topHeight) { //multiple conditions
         $element.addClass(className);
     } else {
         $element.removeClass(className);
     }
 });
 $(window).resize(function() { //reload function when window resized
     var $topHeight = $('.slider_image'); //recalculate $topHeight
     $document.scroll(function() { //re-running function
         if ($(window).width() >= 768) && ($document.scrollTop() >= $topHeight) { //multiple conditions
             $element.addClass(className);
         } else {
             $element.removeClass(className);
         }
     });
 });
```